# Can we send the data from one nodejs app to another nodejs app using MQTT module?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

Normally, MQTT module is used to send messages for communication purpose. I am a beginner in nodejs programming. Am I able to send the data from one node app to another app using MQTT module? If it is possible can anyone tell me 
how to do so?

Comment: As it stands it is not clear what you are asking here. Please read the doc about how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Client: https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js

Server: https://github.com/mcollina/mosca

Take at look at their documentation. They have great examples.